# Global poker taxes

Tags: taxes, gambling

Global Poker is a US facing site that uses sweepstakes laws as a "loophole" for online poker. The way it works is you can buy "gold coins" which are totally worthless. However, when you buy gold coins you also get "sweeps coins" which and be cashed back out for real money. The larger your gold coin purchase the larger the bonus of sweeps coins you get. The highest purchase level is $2,000. You get x number of gold coins and 2100 sweepscoins. After playing through the sweepscoins on poker tables at least once you can withdraw to your bank account as an ACH transfer.

My question: Is the entire withdraw ammount taxable? Normally, whether you play poker in real life or online at a non-regulated site, you should only have to pay taxes on winnings-buyins. But for this, you aren't "depositing" in the traditional sense. If the entire amount is taxable, can you expense your initial buyins?

Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't matter what they call it, if it increases your net worth, it is typically taxable income.

Comment: Maybe I should have worded this better. I don't mind paying taxes on the part that increases my net worth, I just don't want to make sure I'm not paying on the cycle (or I'll go broke)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revenue - expense = profit

And profit from a proprietor business activity is income.

To start with, the gambling income can go on Line 8 of a Schedule 1. Otherwise a Schedule C is available. If business property is bought and sold then a Form 4797 is available.

A record of the financial activity is funds paid-out and funds received. Of course funds credited but not withdrawn need to be accounted.